# CountRows expression appears multiple times within the group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a simple SSRS tablix with two fields - Age Bracket and # of deaths per age bracket (for particular condition). The report is grouped by Age Bracket and # of deaths is count of records per Age Bracket.

I'm using the following formula for # of deaths:

```
     CountRows("Age_Bracket")
```

Here is the tablix in design mode:

[image]

However, in Report Preview I see this (# of death appears multiple times per the same Age Bracket):

[image]

How to eliminate duplicates, so the report will appear like this?

[image]

Comment: You have both the AGE BRACKET grouping and Details. You didn't to add the Age Bracket group, just add the Grouping to the current Details group (and rename to Age Bracket if desired). You also don't need the group name in the count rows when it's done correctly.

Comment: Thank you, it worked like this:
1.  Expression formula:       CountRows("Details")
2. Grouping:                      Under Details group added "Age Bracket" group

Comment: right click on the (Details) under the Age_Bracket Group under the Row Group  and delete it.